# Why must I call Focus() after my button click event for seamless behavior?

Tags: wpf, xaml, event-handling

I have a `SearchTextBox` custom control, pictured here:

[image: SearchTextBox]

When the mouse clicks on it, that label disappears. If the user clicks away and there is no text, the label reappears (if the user clicks away but leaves text there, the text stays and the label stays hidden). This button replaces the image when the user starts typing:

[image: SearchTextBox2]

When the user clicks the button, the text is cleared.

That's all working correctly. The odd behavior I'm talking about is that when the clear button is clicked, the label flashes on the control for a split-second before disappearing (it should remain hidden the entire time). Because the `Multitrigger` in the XAML uses `IsFocused`, I thought maybe I could fix the problem simply by calling `Focus()` in the code-behind before the `Click` event finishes. This seems a little hacky, but it actually worked. My question is, why do I have to do that to make it work "right?"

Snippet from Generic.xaml:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" Color="#ababab"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ui:SearchTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="LabelText" Value="Search for..." />
        <Setter Property="LabelTextColor" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ui:SearchTextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label x:Name="LabelText"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelTextColor}"
                                   Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelText}"
                                   Padding="0"
                                   Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                   FontStyle="Italic"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0"/>
                            <Image x:Name="Image" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Hidden" Source="search2.png" Width="15" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Width="15" Height="15">
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Source="searchstop.png" />
                                </Border>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                            <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Button" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
                                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="LabelText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

SearchTextBox.cs:

```
    public class SearchTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextColorProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasTextProperty;
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasTextPropertyKey;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty;
        private static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty;

        static SearchTextBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SearchTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SearchTextBox)));

            LabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(SearchTextBox));
            LabelTextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelTextColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(SearchTextBox));
            HasTextPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasText", typeof(bool), typeof(SearchTextBox), new PropertyMetadata());
            HasTextProperty = HasTextPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
            SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(SearchTextBox));
            IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsMouseLeftButtonDown", typeof(bool), typeof(SearchTextBox), new PropertyMetadata());
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            HasText = Text.Length != 0;
        }

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush LabelTextColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(LabelTextColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelTextColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool HasText
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HasTextProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(HasTextPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        public bool IsMouseLeftButtonDown
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty, value); }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            Button b = GetTemplateChild("PART_Button") as Button;
            if (b != null)
            {
                b.Click += OnClick;
            }

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Text = "";
            Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flashing most likely occurs because the focus is moving away from your control to the clear button if you press it.
You can fix that be making the clear button non-focusable, i.e.

```
<Button x:Name="PART_Button" Focusable="False" ... />
```

Then the focus does not move when you press the button.